# Solving a system involving a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I have this question:
Solve the system

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & -5 \\ 5 & -2 \end{bmatrix} x
$$

with 
$$x(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

From my notes I figured out it has a spiral trajectory, spinning counter clockwise.
I also need to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ but I can't figure it out.

Note, those equations include matrices, that I wasn't sure how to draw in the question

Comment: The problem would be easy if the coefficient matrix were diagonal.  It's not, unfortunately, but if you can diagonalize the coefficient matrix that is almost as good.

Comment: @littleO how would I go about doing that? Im just starting to learn about matrices so I'm not familiar with them yet

Comment: The initial value problem defined by $\dot x=Ax$ with $x(0)=x_0$ have the general solution $x(t)=e^{tA}x_0$.

The complicate thing here is the calculation of the exponential of the matrix $tA$.

Comment: @rebellos thank you, I really appreciate you trying to help me but I'm not sure I understand what you did? I don't think I'm familiar with the way you are attempting to solve it..

Comment: I will add: in this case computing $e^{tA}$ is easy because $A$ have the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{smallmatrix}\right]=a\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]+\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-b\\b&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, where these two last matrices commute, thus $$e^{tA}=e^{at}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\cos(bt)&-\sin(bt)\\\sin(bt)&\cos(bt)\end{smallmatrix}\right]$$ what can be checked from the definition of the exponential map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is :

$$\Bigg(\begin{matrix} x_1'\\ x_2' \end{matrix}\Bigg) = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & -5 \\ 5 & -2 \end{bmatrix} \Bigg(\begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{matrix} \Bigg)$$

So :

$$x_1' = -2x_1 -5x_2$$

$$x_2' = 5x_1 -2x_2 $$

It's easy to solve :

$$x_1' = -2x_1 - 5x_2 \Rightarrow \dots \Rightarrow x_1 =c_1e^{-2x_2} + \frac{5x_2}{2} - \frac{5}{4}$$

So, finally, you'll have to solve :

$$x_2' = 5c_1e^{-2x_2} + \frac{25x_2}{2} - \frac{25}{4} - 2x_2 \Rightarrow \dots$$

Can you solve this one and yield your final result ?

Remember that you can simplify $x_1$ and thus $x_2$ by your initial values :

$$x(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{cases} x_1(0) = 1 \\ x_2(0) = -3\end{cases}$$

Comment: There's a problem: the eigenvalues are complex, hence the exponential of the matrix will involve trigonometric functions.

Comment: @Rebellos: Are you sure this result and approach is correct?

Comment: The term with $e^{-2\color{red}{x_2}}$ looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to $\dot x = Ax$ is

$$
x(t) = e^{At}x(0) = e^{-2t}\begin{bmatrix}\cos{5t}&-\sin{5t}\\\sin{5t}&\cos{5t} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-3\end{bmatrix}
$$

The tedious part is calculating the matrix exponential and you can consult any textbook or online source for it.

Well, ..., this was already given in the comments anyways here is the computed version

Answer (score 0):

If you change the variables
$$
\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{bmatrix}=e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}
$$
then you will get
$$
\begin{cases}
z_1'=-5z_2,\\
z_2'=5z_1.
\end{cases}
$$
If you differentiate it once again, you may notice that both $z_k$ are solutions to $y''+25y=0$. Solve it and adapt the initial values to find $z_k$ and after that $x_k$.

Comment: Im just not sure where you got the variable z from and how to convert it back to x? Again I'm new with matrices so I might need the process spelled out for me!

Comment: Since both equations have similar terms  we can get rid of those by changing $x_k'+2x_k$ to $z_k'$. It is the same idea in this change as in the integrating factor method. To convert it back is easy: $x(t)=e^{-2t}z(t)$.